# Operator in separable Banach space is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Define the operator $T:ℓ^1 \rightarrow X$ as $T(a_n)=\sum_{n=1}a_nx_n$ where $X$ is a separable Banach space and $(x_n)$ is a dense sequence in $B_X$.

(1) First, I need to show that $T$ is well-defined and bounded by $1$. Simply speaking this should be equivalent to showing $a_n=b_n \Rightarrow T(a_n)=T(b_n)$ but I don't think this is correct in this case.

(2) The next thing to show is that $T(ℓ^1)$ is dense in $X$.

Well, a separable Banach space means that there is a dense subset in $X$. I'm also not sure what $B_X$ means in this task. $T(ℓ^1)=X$ so to show that it is dense in $X$ I need to show that $\overline{X}=X$?

Comment: I would guess that $\ B_X\ $ is either the unit ball, $\ \{\,x\in X\,|\,\|x\|\le1\,\} \ $, or the unit sphere, $\ \{\,x\in X\,|\,\|x\|=1\,\} \ $, of $\ X\ $, but you really need to clarify this with whoever gave you the task.

Answer (score 1):

The operator $T$ is well defined as the series
$\sum a_n x_n$ is absolutely convergent, therefore convergent. Moreover
$$\|T(a_n)\|_X\le \sum |a_n|\,\|x_n\|_X\le \sum |a_n|$$ hence $\|T\|\le 1.$
The range of $T$ is dense in $B_X$ as
$Te_n=x_n,$ where $\{e_n\}$ denotes the standard basis in $\ell^1.$ Besides it gives $\|T\|\ge 1,$ hence $\|T\|=1.$

As
$X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (nB_x)$ the range of $T$ is dense in $X.$

Let's replace the assumption by: $x_n$ is dense in $S_X=\{x\,:\,\|x\|=1\}.$ Then for any $x\neq 0$ the element $x/\|x\|$ is a limit of  a subsequence $x_{n_k}=T(e_{n_k}).$ Then $T(\|x\|e_{n_k})=\|x\|T(e_{n_k})$ tends to $x,$ i.e. the range of $T$ is dense.

Comment: @Zerox I does, as $\{x_n\}$ is dense in the unit ball.

Comment: Oh, now I see why. Then this is a perfect answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well-definedness really follows from boundedness, so we'll skip well-definedness and jump to showing boundedness and then density.

Recall our norm on $\ell^1$ is

$$\|(a_n)\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|.$$

Let $B_X := \{x \in X \ | \ \|x\| = 1\}$ (note: you should have your instructor clarify what they mean, it could be the unit ball instead of the unit sphere). Let $(x_n) \subseteq B_X$ be a dense sequence, and define $T : \ell^1 \rightarrow X$ by

$$ T(a_n) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x_n.$$

- Our goal is to show that $T$ is bounded. The first step in boundedness is to try supposing $\|(a_n)\| = 1$. What's the first inequality that you would get if you tried to calculate boundedness?

> You should get something like
>  $$\|T(a_n)\| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|a_n x_n\| =   \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| \|x_n\|.$$

Now examining this, recall that $(x_n) \subseteq B_X$. What can we conclude from here?

> Since $(x_n) \subseteq B_X$, we have $\|x_n\| = 1$. Hence
>  $$\|T(a_n)\| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| = \|(a_n)\| = 1.$$

We can now conclude that $T$ is bounded.  Note that if $B_X$ is the unit ball instead, then this still works and we have that it is bounded. Moreover, recall that bounded implies continuity: [A is bounded implies A is continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903200/a-is-bounded-implies-a-is-continuous)

- Our goal now is to show that $T(\ell^1)$ is dense. Recall that density follows if we can show that for each $y \in X$ we can find a sequence $(y_n) \subseteq T(\ell^1)$ such that $y_n \rightarrow y$. To that end, take $y \in B_X$. What we can we do in this case?

> If $y \in B_X$, then since $(x_n)$ is dense in $B_X$ we can find a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $x_{n_k} \rightarrow y$. Now let $(a_n) \in \ell^1$ be the element which is $1$ if $n = n_k$ and $0$ otherwise, so $T(a_n) = x_{n_k}.$ Then $T(a_n) \rightarrow y$.

Now if we don't know that $y \in B_X$, what can we do? An easy one to deal with is if $y = 0$, so what if $y \in X \setminus \{0\}$?

> If we normalize, so take $y/\|y\|$, then this has norm $1$, so $y/\|y\| \in B_X.$ Now we can do our procedure above to deal with $y/\|y\|$, and then if we replace $1$ with $\|y\|$ we have that $T(a_n) \rightarrow y$, as desired.

Note that this same argument works if $B_X$ is the unit ball instead of the unit sphere.